# Проблема переключения слайдов JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите разобратся с багом в слайдере.

1-баг При  последной итерацци блок всплывает поздновато (**виден белый фон**).

2-баг После перезагрузки страницы кнопка `prev` работает неправильно.

Заранее Спасибо.

```js
const NEXT = document.querySelector('#next');
const PREV = document.querySelector('#prev');
const SLIDES = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
const ITEM = document.querySelector('.slider-item');
let index = 0;


NEXT.addEventListener('click', function() {
  index++;
  ITEM.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    if (index >= SLIDES.length) {
      index = 0;
      this.style.transition = "none";
      this.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + index * 100 + '%)';
    }
  });
  ITEM.style.transition = "0.7s";
  ITEM.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + index * 100 + '%)';

});

PREV.addEventListener('click', function() {
  index--;
  ITEM.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    if (0 > index) {
      index = SLIDES.length + 1;
      this.style.transition = "none";
      this.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + index * 100 + '%)';
    }
  });
  ITEM.style.transition = "0.7s";
  ITEM.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + index * 100 + '%)';
  console.log(index);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header.banner {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

div.slider-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.slider-item {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

div.slide {
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 150px 0;
}

span#next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 15%;
  z-index: 10000;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span#prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 15%;
  z-index: 10000;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="banner">
  <div class="container-fluid slider-wrapper">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap slider-item">
      <div class="slide" style="background-color: black;"></div>
      <div class="slide" style="background-color: red;"></div>
      <div class="slide" style="background-color: green;"></div>
      <div class="slide" style="background-color: indigo;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span id="next">></span>
  <span id="prev"><</span>
</header>
```

Comment: Вы же подключаете Bootstrap. Чем вам не угодил стандартный [слайдер](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#with-controls)?

Comment: Я для примера  использую  bootstrap

Comment: owl carousel более практичен.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше все переделать и сделать все слайды подряд с помощью css а потом просто с помощью 
js получать количество слайдов, задать их размер в пикселях и создать переменную со значением сдвига (по умолчанию = 0, например left). Потом просто по клику на стрелку увеличивать переменную left на ширину слайда и задавать родительскому диву позицию left: -200px например, потом left: -400px; и например всего слайдов 5, max_left 5*200 (пусть каждый слайд будет по 200 пикселей). и дальше if (left > max_left) {left = 0}

Лучше посмотрите данное видео:
[Как создать слайдер](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=casgv9Y8I1w)